# How to update a variable within multiple functions: Powerball game

Tags: python, global

New to Python, but learning through struggling and trying to make good practices. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction for my python program: the powerball. It's between the computer and user, where each pick 3 unique (non duplicated) numbers between 1-9, and a powerball number between 1-3. I wanted to add a money variable that would be shared between the main() function, (which tells you 'welcome' and 'your current money is: (money)), and also shared between the compare_winnings() function, which compares my two lists, and adds the total to the (money) variable.

I've done some research through google and SO, and found that placing my money variable outside of every function turns it into a 'global variable', which seems useful since it'll be used in 2 functions. I've also learned that using the syntax 'global' is bad practice. However, the code runs fine and within the compare_winnings() function, the money is updated. When the game prompts you if you would like to play again (another function), it then starts over, and the money is back to its original value. (which starts at 20).

```
def main():
  print("Each ticket costs $1. Your winnings will be totaled. Current money is",money, "dollars." )
  start = input("\n Are you ready? [y/n]: ")

  if start == "y" or start == "yes":      
    #erased variables for legibility; gathers numbers from computer and user
    compare_winnings(actual, chosen,cpb, comp_cpb,money)
  else: 
    play_again()
```

```
def compare_winnings(actual, chosen, cpb, comp_cpb,money):
  counter = 0
  print("You chose: ", chosen) #user-inputted
  print("Ticket was actually: ", actual) #random (actual)

  same_values = set(actual) & set(chosen)
  #print ("These are the values that are the same",same_values)
  if len(same_values) > 0:
    counter += len(same_values)
    print("Numbers correct was : ",counter)

    if counter == 1 and cpb != comp_cpb :
      print("You won $1")
      money += 1
      print("total money is:", money)
      play_again()
```

```
def play_again():
  play = input("Do you want to play again? ")
  if play == "y" or play == "yes":
    main()
  else: 
    print("Program will exit. Thanks for playing.")
```

I expect for the money variable to be updated (and kept) until they decide to stop playing the game. However, it seems to be restarted when they decide to play again and or at main().

Comment: Declare the variable outside any of the functions. Declare them as global in side the functions with `global variable_name`

Comment: I was made aware that using 'global' to use variables outside of many functions was a bad thing to be doing. Is there any other way?

Comment: In your case, you're storing your program state (which is global) in these variables. So using `global` is the straight-forward approach. There's a thin-line between using `global` because it makes sense and abusing `global` to avoid passing arguments to functions. Take it on a case-by-case basis. Use your judgement. There's no hard-and-fast rule about it.